# How load balancer discovers new instances that are added?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-auto-scaling

i am having an alb which is configured to load balance a target group (instance based).
there is also an auto scaling policy defined with same alb for 80% cpu utilisation.
the servers are running on port 8080 and the same is defined in the target group.

1. i want to understand how and when alb checks what is cpu utilisation of the instances?
2. lets say the cpu utilisation becomes > 80%, a new instance would be launched. how does the alb discovers it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ALB does not monitor the CPU usage of instances at all. The Autoscaling Group monitors the CPU usage of the instances, and adds or removes instances as needed to maintain your desired CPU usage. When the Autoscaling Group adds or removes instances, it updates the instances in the Target Group. The ALB simply checks the Target Group for the list of instances it can send traffic to.

Comment: when does the alb checks the target group for the list of instances, is it time based like per second?

Comment: Whenever it receives a request that it needs to send to an instance. It isn't some cron-job type of thing, it simply uses the target group every time it receives a request it needs to forward on.

Comment: Per [Registered targets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#registered-targets): "The load balancer starts routing requests to a newly registered target as soon as the registration process completes and the target passes the initial health checks."

Comment: @MarkB 1. how does the auto scaling group monitors the cpu usage, is it cron based like per second. can you share any documentation link on how it works.

2. where does the alb keep list of instances inside the target group, is it like in-memory or does it call an api of target group to get list of instances per request?

Comment: The ASG responds to metrics stored in CloudWatch.  While the [metrics themselves are documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html), the exact technical source isn't.  Likely it's from the hypervisor, but the how is largely an implementation detail.